# How to correctly interact between Mono?

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm new using the Spring Webflux and I was able to join the results between two rest API with the code:

```
return item.zipWith(children).flatMap(tuple -> {
        tuple.getT1().setItems(tuple.getT2());
        return Mono.just(tuple.getT1());
    });
```

Item is a Mono and children a Mono<List>.
My questions are:

- is this a good implementation or it's a blocking one that waste the feature of Reactive programming?
- There is a better way to do it?
- I couldn't find a clear list of non-blocking/blocking operations, anybody knows if there is one?

Comment: This is non-blocking. Method names and/or javadoc clearly indicate if an operator is blocking. There are not many of them. Examples: `block...` methods, `toIterable`, `toStream`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:
If `children` is `List` type, it is better to make it as a `Flux` type is better, and you could use `Flux.fromIterable(List)` method to transform `List` to `Flux`.

Therefor, the `children` can receive elements and be delivered into `item` non-blocking.